# Changed my C# code but the exe not updated accordingly

Tags: c#

After changing something in my C# code, I can run it without problem. However, if I run the .exe file in WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/Debug/, I would get an error message. By checking the 'Date modified' of this .exe file, I found it wouldn't update accordingly.

I then tried to do Build/Build Solution and Rebuild Solution but the .exe file would still not be updated.

Can you tell me how to update the .exe file?

Comment: Is your build configuration set to Release?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the PDB file in the build directory?

Comment: do a (build menu) clean then rebuild, then move this question to stackoverflow

Comment: [Is your build configuration set to Release?–  CodeCaster]: Can you tell me where to do the configuration?

Comment: [Have you tried deleting the PDB file in the build directory? – Mothermole1]: Do you mean I need to delet the PDB file every time when I need to update the exe file?

Comment: [do a (build menu) clean then rebuild, then move this question to stackoverflow – radarbob]: How to move this question to stackoverflow and what is that? Sorry, I an new here...

Answer (score 6):

To view the output directory for your builds, right-click on the project you are trying to build and select "Properties". Under the "Build" tab you should find the following:

[image: Build tab of the Properties page]

At the top you can also see the configuration under which your project is building (usually Debug or Release). By default, the output directory for Debug and Release builds are, respectively, "bin\Debug" and "bin\Release". **EDIT:** To change which build configuration is currently active, you will need to go to Build -> Configuration Manager:

[image]

Once you have checked the build directory paths and the configuration which you are building, do a Clean Solution followed by a Build Solution and your *.exe file should now be the latest version.

Hope this helps!

Alex

**EDIT:**

Apologies - meant also to mention that the build directory paths are relative to the project directory (the directory where the *.csproj file for your project lives). So updating the *.exe file in WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug under Debug configuration with the default output directory is contingent upon WindowsFormsApplication1.csproj being contained in the WindowsFormsApplication1 directory.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you so much for your Fig!
I followed your instruction:
From the right side Solution Explorer - WindowsFormsApplication1
I right clicked the empty space,
select properties -> found the Output path was bin\Debug\
I then did Build -> Clean Solution -> the exe was still there!
Finally, I did Build -> Build Solution -> the exe didnt be updated, still got the same 'Date modified'.

I am so sad.....

Comment: Hmm, that is indeed an interesting one... I'm just trying to re-create your issue now, but in the mean time can I just confirm that your project is still running correctly from inside Visual Studio? (that is, when you F5 it?)

Comment: Also, please see my edit about how to change the active configuration. Only as a sanity check really- I did just have to check for myself that selecting a configuration from the drop-down box on the Properties page doesn't actually change how the solution is building!

Comment: Before the problem happened, I can run it correctly by click the triangle or by double click /bin/Debug/the.exe. A few days ago, after I changed my code I got error when double click the.exe file, while got no problem when click the triangle and no problem at the moment by press F5 as you just suggested. 

Actually, I didn't fully understand what you mean in your EDIT. I tried doble click WindowsFormsApplication1.csproj and got the same window as the one I got by double click WindowsFormsApplication1.sln.

Comment: Hmm, well assuming that it runs fine from Visual Studio (i.e. when you F5 or press Start), an updated *.exe file is being built _somewhere_. The compiler will throw an error if it is not able to write to the build output path (i.e. if access is denied) so assuming you do a clean before you run, a new *.exe _is_ being built, otherwise nothing would happen. I will head-scratch some more... In my edit I was just explaining that the "project directory" is where the *.csproj file lives, and that the build output paths are relative to that. Clicking on *.csproj or *.sln will just open Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, by double click WindowsFormsApplication1.csproj or double click WindowsFormsApplication1.sln will open the same WindowsFormsApplication1 - Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok, I think we may be at cross-purposes slightly. My understanding is that you would like to configure the build path of the *.exe file for your Windows Forms Application. If my answer hasn't helped you to achieve this then you may want to consider re-installing Visual Studio, as your project isn't building to the output path of the active configuration (assuming you followed my steps :O) ). I would be happy to discuss this further in chat but I feel we may be drifting slightly from the original question...

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I have enough skill to have chat with you - You may already find my English is not good enough.
What I will try is to rewrite my project again and see what will happen. If I got anything interesting or very strange I will let your know.
Thanks a lot for your time and patient

Answer (score 2):

Somehow I figured out why it is happening. If you have multiple projects in a solution (I assume that's the case above), check the status of "Build" checkbox in the property pages. I faced same issue when one of my three projects under solution was not refreshing whenever I rebuild the solution.

[image]

Hope this will help!